# Hidden Markov Model: How to deal with multiple symbols emitted from a given state

Tags: references, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I would like to build a HMM that would work similarly to a parts-of-speech tagger. But rather than tag words in a sentence with their part of speech, I would tag words in user searches on e-commerce sites with their category. For instance, both "red party dress" and "black formal tie" would be tagged with `[color] [occasion] [item]`.

I have a basic understanding of my approach with one exception: How should I deal with multi-term elements in the search string? For instance "American Eagle" is a two token `[brand name]`; "bathing suit" is a two token `[item]`; and "periwinkle blue" is a two token `[color]`. So I would like for "periwinkle blue American Eagle bathing suit" to have only three tags, namely `[color] [brand name] [item]`.

The approach that I'm following comes from chapter 6 of [this really excellent book](http://lintool.github.com/MapReduceAlgorithms/MapReduce-book-final.pdf), but it just doesn't deal with multi-token symbols or equivalently multiple symbols emitted during a particular state.

- What are your ideas?
- Are there any papers that you can refer me to?

Comment: Have you heard about hierarchical HMMs? It seems like that's what you would need.

Comment: @jerad woo no... do you have any links to good resources?